# При запуске Vagrant выдаёт ошибку

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Уже много времени потратил на решение ошибки при запуске Vagrant. Что я делал:
1. Скачал Vagrant. (vagrant -v -> Vagrant 2.2.4)
2. С помощью сервиса puphpet.com создал Vagrantfile и папки конфигурации
3. Распаковал архив, созданный puphpet.com (Vagrantfile и др.) и поместил в папку проекта: m2/www/project
4. Запустил команду в консоли vagrant up и получил ошибку:

```
C:\Users\Alexey\Documents\m2\www\project>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'm2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> m2: Box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    m2: Box Provider: virtualbox
    m2: Box Version: >= 0
==> m2: Loading metadata for box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'
    m2: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/ubuntu-16.04
==> m2: Adding box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' (v201812.27.0) for provider: virtualbox
    m2: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04/versions/201812.27.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    m2: Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
    m2:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Ошибка при загрузке удалённого файла. А как её исправить? И почему она возникла? Из всех советов ни один не помог, этот в том числе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874260/error-when-trying-vagrant-up 
Если создавать Vagrantfile с помощью vagrant init hashicorp/precise32 , то при vagrant up вылезет та же самая ошибка. SLL-сертификат не при чём, вроде бы или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Мне помогло- выгрузить Касперского.